# How to build my pure Java (Swing) apps for Android 5.0?

Tags: java, android

The Android 5.0 page states that 'Pure Java language apps run as 64-bit apps automatically'.  I cannot find any documentation on how to configure/build my java apps for Android 5.0.  Has anybody had any success with this yet?

Comment: Never heard of a pure java port for Android. Wouldn't seem like something someone would work on since Android is already Java based, but could be wrong.

Comment: You don't use Swing on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what they meant: they meant that Android applications without an [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) component built in C/C++ (i.e., built entirely on the Java based Android SDK) will automatically be compatible with 64 bit processor devices, not that desktop/Swing Java apps will run on Android devices.